# Android building using build.sh script

Tags: java, android, linux, shell, android-manifest

I really need help about building android using build.sh script. On our build.sh there is a command which looks like this:

Let's assume that **appName = "com.newbuild.configuration"**.

```
parm1="s/package=\"com.default.packagename\"/package=\""$appName"\"/g"
find ../../ -name \AndroidManifest.xml -exec sed -i $parm1 {} \;
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, this command means that on it should find the **AndroidManifest.xml** then it should replace the `package="com.default.packagename"` by `package="com.newbuild.configuration"`.

Now my problem is, I have a certain permission (for GCM) and I need to change also the package name for that permission. How can I achieve it using this script? or do I need to create another `parm` to do this?

From this one:

```
<permission
    android:name="com.default.packagename.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="com.default.packagename.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

to this:

```
<permission
    android:name="com.newbuild.configuration.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="com.newbuild.configuration.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:

I just added another **parm** that will modify those two permissions:

```
parm2="s/android:name=\"com.default.packagename.permission.C2D_MESSAGE\"/android:name=\""$appName".permission.C2D_MESSAGE\"/g"
find ../../ -name \AndroidManifest.xml -exec sed -i $parm2 {} \;
```